# What could be causing my oven to display an error when touched?

Tags: oven

Often, when I touch my oven, especially in the area of the controller, the oven controller lights up completely and resets to "PF". or Power failure. I then need to set the clock all over again and wait for the next episode. Whirlpool sent a service person who changed the circuit board. Same problem exists after a week. When I touch the oven I feel a small static electricity zap. Any ideas?

Comment: How's the ground connection on your stove? Seems to me that modern electronics shouldn't do that if everything's hooked up right.

Comment: Has this always happened with this oven? Did you install the oven? Is it a wall oven or part of a free-standing stove?

Answer (score 2):

There are two causes that come to mind.  Either you have a build up of static electricity in your body and you are discharging it into the oven, causing the controller to reset, or something in the oven is shorting out to the chasis causing you to get shocked when you touch it.

Do you commonly get static shocks anywhere else in your house?  This is common in northern climates in the winter when everything is really dry.  Often you can improve this by increasing the humidity in your house.

If you do not have static issues elsewhere then it is likely that something is wrong with your oven in the form of a short.  I would advise not to use it any further and have a service person come back and check it more carefuly.  Heating elements failing is a common cause of this.

Comment: There is no such thing as being "mildly electrocuted".  You are either electrocuted; and your heart stops, or you were shocked.

Comment: Don't check for voltage, unplug the stove and check for continuity between hot an ground and hot and the body of the stove.

Comment: If it were a short in say the controller then I don't think this would show anything, only if the short was in a line-voltage component.  I removed this part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you finish checking the oven for shorts or a bad ground, then the problem might be another appliance next to the oven, like a toaster or blender thats not grounded correctly. Check to see what receptacles are on the circuits in the kitchen and make sure all plugs and receptacles are properly grounded. If there are multiple GFCI's on the same circuit will cause problems if wired incorrectly. You can buy a plug that has 3 indicator lights that check  110/125 v receptacles  for proper voltage and ground. They are cheap, like 10 bucks.

Good Luck.

Comment: Testers cannot usually tell the difference between ground and neutral so I would not rely on one for this..

Answer (score -1):

1. If the shock you feel is only momentary, then it would be static
   discharge from your finger to the display circuitry via the display
   panel.  If you touch ground to discharge your static charge right
   before you touch the panel, you should see no malfunction.  (If you still do, the display panel would most likely be defective and need
   replacement, assuming it was correctly installed to begin with.)
2. If the shock you feel is persistent (when you keep your finger pressed), it's current, rather than static, electricity and would come from an ungrounded panel surround that has somehow come in contact with a significantly high voltage.  That would signal a potentially dangerous defect in the oven or the installation, and is sufficient reason to open the breaker immediately and call an electrician.
3. Back to #1:  If it's static causing the problem, your immediate work around is to discharge your finger by touching a nearby grounded surface (sink, water faucet, someplace on the oven, etc.) before touching the display.  It's not something I would recommend for the long run (for many reasons, one is the chance of ruining the display with one of those discharge shocks, another is the chance of setting the stove in a mode or at a temperature you did not want, and not noticing until you've tested your smoke detector).  There are antistatic sprays that you can try, or if you can find some glycerine, try wiping a film over the display.  It's hygroscopic to a degree, and the thin film may serve as a conductive shield to divert the static charge to ground.

Good luck, and let us know how it works out!

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the other answers that have been here for _12 years_. While there's nothing wrong with answering old questions, _please_ make sure you're bringing something new to the table. [How to write a good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) will help.

Comment: Ouch!  I appreciate the feedback and suggestion, but I actually thought I did bring something new to the table:  1- specific method to differentiate between static and current electricity as the cause of the problem.  2- two novel work-arounds for static electricity.  3- a warning that a current electricity fault could be dangerous and the power should be shut off until an electrician can determine the cause (vs calling a service person to repair the appliance, which would risk allowing a shock hazard in the kitchen).  I hope you will reconsider your down vote, for it lowers my credibility.